# Can't overfit Transformer Encoder

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, transformer, overfitting

In the below code I am trying to train a very simple Transformer Encoder model to basically do nothing with its input. Giving some arbitrary input vector x, the aim of the model is then to output that exact same vector. As my loss function I am using the Mean Squared Error, between my input vector x and the output vector y. So the optimal solution would be located at y=x. However apart from very simple input vector shapes where for example the batch size, sequence length and feature dimension are all one, the model always seems to get stuck at some non marginal loss.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim


class Transformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, feedforward_expansion, num_layers):
        super().__init__()   
        
        layer = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=d_model, nhead=1, 
                                           dim_feedforward=d_model * feedforward_expansion,
                                           batch_first=True)
        
        self.encoder = nn.TransformerEncoder(layer, num_layers=num_layers)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        y = self.encoder(x)
        
        return y
    
    
n_batch, n_sequence, n_features = 10, 10, 10
lr = 1e-2
n_epochs = 1000
num_layers = 1
feedforward_expansion = 1
    
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
model = Transformer(n_features, feedforward_expansion, num_layers)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)

x = torch.randn((n_batch, n_sequence, n_features))

for i in range(n_epochs):    
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    y = model(x)
    loss = criterion(x, y)
    
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    print(f"{i}: {loss.item():.4e}")
```

I assume this has something to do with the architecture of the Transformer. However I am wondering if someone could explain me in more detail why this model seems to fail at this rather simple task?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to do justice in a single answer, but I can refer you to two excellent resources: https://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/ and https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-01-27-the-transformer-family-v2/. The short version of this is that transformers are sequence-to-sequence models, and you're passing essentially an unpredictable sequence of random numbers.